# Getting EURO symbol in content of VI editor in unix

Tags: unix, vi

I am trying to write a script and I need to type the EURO symbol that needs to be printed in the output.

If I type the same in any editor and paste it to VI editor it changes to a dot(.).

Can someone help me on how to type the Euro symbol into the content in VI editor.

Comment: What is the default codepage for your shell, and the default codepage for your terminal (e.g. PuTTY)?

Comment: One problem in offering an answer is that it depends on what OP's keyboard is, what the encoding (and locale settings) on the remote system are.  For many combinations there is no practical answer.

Comment: Hi All, Thank you. I got a solution based on all your inputs i.e I changed my putty's translation settings to Latin-9 "euro" and VI allowed me to paste Euro symbol across windows and putty. But now I got another problem where my java program, to which this value is input, is throwing an error saying "invalid 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence" when its trying to parse the euro symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there try to press on keyboard ALT + 0128 :)

Comment: So, press the ALT key and while holding down... Press numbers 0,1,2,8

Comment: Thanks for answer. I opened the file in VI and tried your solution in both insert and esc mode but nothing happens :( Am I missing to do something?

Comment: Huh - so you are using VI on a **Windows** system (codepage WIN-1252)?!?

Comment: Yes. I am accessing unix using putty from a windows system. Can some one tell me the command I should use to make an echo command display the EURO symbol. I am using bash shell.